# PDE Method of characteristics with initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I wanted to solve the following PDE with initial condition
$$ u_t+tu_x=0, $$
$$ u(x,1)=f(x),$$
where $f(x)$ is a given function, using the method of characteristics.

I explain what I have done. First of all the characteristic system is
$$ x'(\tau)=t $$ 
$$ t'(\tau)=1 $$
$$ u'(\tau)=u $$
with initial conditions
$$ x(s,1)=s $$
$$ t(s,1)=1 $$
$$ u(s,1)=f(s) $$

It follows that 
$$x(s,\tau)=\tau^2+s-1,$$ 
$$t(s,\tau)=\tau,$$
$$u(s,\tau)=e^{\tau-1}f(s).$$ Therefore,
$s=x-t^2+1$ and $\tau=t$. Hence 
$$ u(x,t)=u(x-t^2+1,t)=e^{t-1}f(x-t^2+1).$$

But this is wrong because it does not satisfy the system. What would be right is
$$ u(x,t)=e^{t-1}f(x-t^2/2+1/2).$$
But I do not know where this $1/2$ can come from...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of $\tau$ is $\tau^2/2$, not $\tau$. It should be
$$
x=\frac{\tau^2}{2}+s-\frac12.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This means that in the characteristic system must be $x'(\tau)=\tau$, not $x'(\tau)=t$, true? In spite of we know $t=\tau$ after solving $t'(\tau)=1$ with initial condition $t(s,1)=1$.

Comment: Yes, that's it.